# Solving a recurrence relation with no real roots?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$a_n - 2a_{n-1} -12a_{n-2} - 14a_{n-3} -5a_{n-4} = 0 $

I've tried a few method:

1. setting the denominator to $1 -2x -12x^2 -14x^3 -5x^4$ and then finding the numerator by multiplying $(1 -2x -12x^2 -14x^3 -5x^4)*\sum a_nx^{n}$
2. finding the roots of C(y) = $y^4 -4y^3 -12y^2 -14y -5$

What else can I do?

Comment: $y^4 - 2y^3 -12y^2-14y-5 = (y-5)(y+1)^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A start: The given recurrence has characteristic equation $x^4-2x^3-12x^2-14x-5=0$. This has $x=-1$ as a solution.

Dividing our polynomial by $x+1$, we get $x^3-3x^2-9x-5$. Note that $-1$ is a zero of this polynomial. Continue.

Comment: Wow... wolfram alpha failed me. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. The general solution of the recurrence turns out to be $A+Bn+Cn^2+D5^n$.

Comment: I finished with $a_n = (7n^2 -3n -1)(-1)^n +2(5)^n $

Comment: The *shape* of your answer is correct. Since your post does not currently give the initial conditions, I have no way of verifying that your coefficients are correct. But if your initial conditions are indeed satisfied, it must be correct.